# Netlify Cron Job in Javascript - PUT call returns error

Tags: javascript, netlify

I have the following code:

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

export default async (req) => {
    if (req.method === 'PUT') {
        const { next_run } = await req.json();
        console.log("Working");
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:8000/matching/connect_request_timeout', {
            method: 'PUT'
        });
        const data = await response.json();
        return new Response("PUT request processed");
    } else {
        return new Response("Non-PUT request received");
    }
}

export const config = {
    schedule: '0 5 * * *'`
}
```

What I want it to do is to call on a PUT request daily at 5am UTC. There are no keys or tokens used for this, and I've tested it manually to ensure the API call works. The problem is that I do not have a lot of javascript experience and I am having a problem handling an undefined: undefined error that netlify returns.

Comment: You will have to provide more detailed info about the deployment setup, the actual error, and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: are you sure that scheduled functions are accessible in a way that you'd be calling with a PUT verb?  It was my understanding that scheduled functions just "run" (you cannot manually execute them at all), and if they have a an HTTP verb associated...it's probably GET.